# Inject.JS file when inspecting headers in chrome network

Tags: javascript

I checked my chrome network tab, when inspecting, and found this script, that looked a bit fishy. It's called inject.js and has this code. I don't have any extensions, called something like this, so I'm worried it might be a malware script?

```
(() => {
try {
const detectJs = (chain) => {
  const properties = chain.split('.');

  let value = properties.length ? window : null;

  for (let i = 0; i < properties.length; i++) {
    const property = properties[i];

    if (value && value.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
      value = value[property];
    } else {
      value = null;

      break;
    }
  }

  return typeof value === 'string' || typeof value === 'number' ? value : !!value;
};

const onMessage = (event) => {
  if (event.data.id !== 'patterns') {
    return;
  }

  removeEventListener('message', onMessage);

  const patterns = event.data.patterns || {};

  const js = {};

  for (const appName in patterns) {
    if (patterns.hasOwnProperty(appName)) {
      js[appName] = {};

      for (const chain in patterns[appName]) {
        if (patterns[appName].hasOwnProperty(chain)) {
          js[appName][chain] = {};

          for (const index in patterns[appName][chain]) {
            const value = detectJs(chain);

            if (value && patterns[appName][chain].hasOwnProperty(index)) {
              js[appName][chain][index] = value;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  postMessage({ id: 'js', js }, '*');
 };

addEventListener('message', onMessage);
  } catch (e) {
 // Fail quietly
  }
   })();
```

Is this some sort of malware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw the same code and determined it was part of Wappalyzer by using the Developer Tools in Chrome, clicking on the Sources tab and searching for inject.js on the Page sub-tab.